# How to calculate percent bias by monthly for all years in a dataset

Tags: r

I want to calculate percent bias between observed and simulated data. But I want to do this by monthly mean for all years. The dataset is called "res". 
The text file has data with month in the first column, simulated data in 2nd column and observed data in 3rd column.

The format of data is as below:

```
DATE       simulated  observed 

01          292.234    305 
02          293.152    320 
03          293.985    324 
04          295.115    308 
05          296.579    326 
06          298.266    344 
07          300.084    342
```

Comment: How is the year specified in the dataset? Since you want to use the monthly mean for all years.

Comment: I removed the years to keep the month only. So January for all years would be 01 in the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be good if you specify your dataset abit more (e.g. you stated you removed "year", but does the month now show the average values of all years?. Also, what do you mean with percent bias exactly?

You can get a long way using the dplyr and SimDesign libraries, for example

```
library(SimDesign)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(DATE) %>% mutate(bias(observed, simulated, type = "relative") * 100)
```

In the code I grouped by DATE, so that the bias is calculated for every unique value of DATE (in this case month, but you probably want to group by month and year in your full dataset). Also, I calculated the relative bias and multiplied it by 100 to get the percent bias measure. Please check this link to see what kind of bias you want to calculate, so you know how to alter the "type" in the code.

Answer (score 0):

With this you get the Bias for each month (same number in test$DATE):

```
library(SimDesign)
for(li in test$DATE){
 k<-bias(test$observed[li], test$simulated[li] )
 print(k)
}
```

Comment: The data is for many years. I want to calculate the monthly mean for all years..is it possible?